# VSCode: terminal clear in cmder

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmder

I use cmder in vscode.
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsTmg.png)
I want to clear all the screen in cmder, I use command
`Terminal: Clear` (`"workbench.action.terminal.clear"`).
After I clear my screen in cmder, I got
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwhcT.png)
My cmder should show
`E:\dev\PY\Reading\CSV`
`λ`
Not show only `λ` character.
When I type anything that is not a command,
it will appear some blank lines that I can't understand what happened
[img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzIAu.png)
and then cmder become the right cmder that I need (with `E:\dev\PY\Reading\CSV` and `λ` and don't have some blank lines anymore) after I press Enter.
Some blank lines also appear when I type some command like `cls`, `clear`
(I don't press Enter)
[img4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2O8r.png)
[img5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIBlV.png)
If I press Enter, my right cmder come back to me.
If I don't press Enter, I use `Terminal: Clear` (2nd times), I lose `λ`
[img6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBBxp.png)
[img7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH2vw.png)
When I type `ls` (but not press Enter), then I press delete 1 time, some blank lines and something strange appear
[img8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwI7m.png)
Can you explain me how to solve that problems, thanks!

Comment: To aid in solving your question please include the code in your question, ensuring it’s formatted.

Comment: @tjheslin1 Oh it is not a code, it is only some problems in cmder which is integrated in vscode